What's the localization of the $\infty$-category of categories under inverting final functors?
The colimit is preserved under pulling back diagrams by a final functor. This could loosely be considered as giving some notion of two categories specifying the same sort of colimit (but since I don't know how to 'push forward' a diagram along a final functor while preserving the colimit, this may not be literal).
This leads to the question of what happens when you make all these final functors invertible. Does this localized category have any interesting homotopical behavior? Is there any simple construction of this object?

Every category becomes equivalent to its set of connected components in this localization, since this set is the midpoint of the comprehensive factorization of the functor $A\to 1$ into a final functor followed by a discrete fibration. In particular, this shows the intuition that categories related by a final functor specify the same sort of colimit is misleading, since pulling back along a final functor produces diagrams which are constant along the fibers of that functor, which may be very special indeed.
The mapping of a category to its set of connected components exhibits the category of sets as a reflective subcategory of the category of categories. Reflective localizations are preserved by the embedding of categories into $\infty$-categories, so the answer is that your localization is just the category of sets.
It's a bit more interesting to localize the slice of categories over $X$ at the final functors over $X$; then you get, in the same way, the category of discrete fibrations over $X.$

Does the $\mathbb N$ poset become equivalent to $1$ since there's a stupid final functor from $\mathbb N$ to $1$?

If we localize at final functors in the $\infty$-categorical sense, we get the $\infty$-category of spaces. The argument you gave just works mutadis mutandis for $\infty$-categories. This works for the localization of the category of 1-categories by final functors in the $\infty$-categorical sense because any $\infty$-category is a localization of a 1-category and localizations are final. We could see that as a fancy way to state Quillen's Theorem A.

Yes, thanks Denis-Charles! To expand a bit, this is the result of localizing at what are sometimes called the homotopy final functors, which are the functors where commas under objects of the codomain are actually contractible, rather than merely nonempty and connected.

How about if you restrict it to require the existence of a inverse final functor in some way? Suppose you demand that you have a pair of final functors, F and G going in opposite directions and there be natural transformations from the identities going to FG and GF such that the resulting maps on colimits are isomorphisms. I think this brings all the countable ordinals together while keeping them separate from 1?

@CharlesWang I'm not sure, because here you're trying to invert some 2-cells instead of some 1-cells and that's a less familiar construction. Pronk and Paré, IIRC, have some papers on localizations of 2-categories but I think their setting still involves weakly inverting 1-cells.
